# .htaccess related codeigniter. why error 404 page not found?

Tags: codeigniter, url

befor I add my website to any hosting I used xampp, so I caller url like :

```
http://localhost/myCI/folderAdmin/controller/
```

in my xampp I use this htaccess file:

```
    Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myCIname/index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

all feature it's work well. but in hosting any error in one page, that give me '404 page not found'. I called url :

```
http://www.myurl.com/folderAdmin/controller/
```

with the htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
      ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
    </IfModule>
```

what's wrong with that? please for help.

thank you for all answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, i solved it by changing

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 folderAdmin/controller/index.php
</IfModule>
```

so you point to the document from the root of your website.

Comment: which controller? first page will be on the run is index.php right?

Comment: I just have one htaccess, I put it in my folder web. am I must make new one?

Comment: @Cha: your htaccess file needs to be in the root of your website.